# Powershell script to create run clean mgr without deleting compressed files

Tags: powershell

Powershell command /script to run clean mgr without deleting compressed files

When searched , cleanmgr.exe /sagerun:10 would perform the clean up activity , but not clear if it meets my requirement for not cleaning compressed file.
Please assist

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking, to see if a sageset is outstanding look at `gci "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches"`  if there are entries `StateFlagsXXXX` those VolumeCaches would be processed on a subsequent sagerun with that number.

Comment: @LotPings, my request is to run cleanmgr to perform disk clean up, without cleaning up compressed files.

Comment: I don't think it matters wether a file is compressed or not, if a file is included in an option **you** select (wether manually or by a script) it will be cleaned. This has nothing to do with the option `compress system disk`. For your question to be on topic here at all you should show your research/coding effort in a [mcve].